# Inhibiting the incompatible pointer type specific warning under GCC

Tags: c, gcc, warnings

In my code under GCC I get quite many warnings of these two types.

```
warning: passing argument 1 of 'foo' from incompatible pointer type
```

and

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

I know that normally, these two are serious warnings indicating something really wrong in the code. In my case though wherever these are happening, I know very well what I am doing and I know I can safely ignore these warnings. (And yes I am sure about it)

But now my code has grown to such an extent that these warnings overshadow anything else, in effect hiding potential warnings that could lead me to a nasty bug. So I decided to inhibit them. Soon I realized I don't know how. My gcc version is 4.4.1 and I know I can use:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignore "-Wname"
```

to ignore any warning I want. But from the only [big and comprehensive list](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) of GCC warnings I found, I can't seem to find which ones these two are. I came to the point of picking them one by one and turning them into errors to see when the compiling would stop due to the incompatible pointer type, but to no avail like below.

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wimplicit-int"   
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Waddress"
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wreturn-type"
           .... //e.t.c.
```

So.. the question is, does anybody know the name of these warnings so that I can actually inhibit them?

**EDIT**

Due to the discussion in the comments I have to clarify a misconception that I had which lead me to believe that I had to inhibit the warnings. I thought that there was some cost (no matter how miniscule) involved in performing explicit casts between pointers to structures.

So my thinking, which I now realized was flawed, was that since my program is working and has been working for a long time under different platforms, why add work to just satisfy the compiler?

Well I now realized, and am writing it here in case anyone else stumbles on this topic and has the same line of thinking. There is no cost involved in performing the explicit typecasting of pointers and the advantages are:

- The compiler stops nagging you with the warnings
- Other people can know that you did the cast intentionally there and did not make mistakes

So here it is for anyone else who might have the same question.

Comment: Always take note of the warnings - they are there for a reason. It is a very very good idea to compile with `-Wall` flag set - and then go about fixing the warnings.

Comment: Out of curiosity, and in no way attempting to doubt your genius, might I ask what this code is that is causing the warning?

Comment: @EdHeal I agree with you and that's why I want to disable these two, because in my code they are not helping me, instead they are overshadowing the other warnings which could be helpful. 

What I need to fix is the compiler inhibiting my work instead of actually helping me with it.I have my reasons for going about ignoring these specific warnings. The question is how to do it so that I can focus on the "real" warnings

Comment: GCC 4.6 decorates every warning with the specific flag that is used to trigger or quell it.

Comment: @Lefteris - Use `grep` perhaps?

Comment: @KerrekSB thanks for that info. Time to upgrade to 4.6 then

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use the `-fdiagnostics-show-option` option, GCC will show you the name of the warning, and you can then disable it.

Disabling the warning is probably not a good idea though: If there is later a legitimate case of this warning, you won't know about it.

You're better off fixing your code to prevent the warning. In your case, this is as easy as adding an explicit pointer cast.

```
float f = 1.23;
char *a = &f; //warning
char *b = (char*)&f; //no warning
```

Using the explicit cast will make it clear to anyone reading the code that changing the pointer type was done deliberately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that an explicit cast would remove the warnings but I am concerned about the cost of a cast. Since the thing I am doing is happening in a big part of a module of my code.

Gotta admit I am not sure what the cost is, and how the compiler actually implements casts. All the warnings are not on primitives but on quite big structures. It's all due to my "emulation" of structure inheritance.

Comment: Actually it seems that -fdiagnostics-show-option shows up the name of almost all the warnings except a few. The two warnings I was interested in are among these few. And from reading here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html

it seems that you can only inhibit warnings that can appear through -fdiagnostics-show-option. Seems that actually inhibiting them under gcc is not an option

Comment: @Lefteris: The cost of an explicit cast is the same as that of an implicit cast.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth so if we have two structs with one having a subset of the data of the other, and we pass a pointer to the bigger one to a function that expects a pointer to the small one an implicit cast happens anyway and the cost would be the same as the explicit one? So .. well is there any actual cost or not? What happens underneath?  

If the cost is virtually the same then I realize that I can just fill it up with explicit casts ...

Comment: @Lefteris: Unless you're on a esoteric platform, nothing at all happens, as data pointers will all have identical representations.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I see. Hey thanks for this insight. It's really helpful. I had the misconception that there was a cost involved filling it with explicit casts everywhere and this is why I was avoiding it since my code is tested under different platform and works fine so far. So basically in C the only reason to cast a pointer to a structure like that is to tell the compiler that you know what you are doing and that it shouldn't worry?

Now the only thing that makes sense is for me to just add explicit casts I guess!

Comment: @Lefteris: It also tells other readers/maintainers of your code that you know what you're doing (i.e. it's an intentional act).

Comment: @Lefteris Also keep in mind that for some other compilers, "worry" in cases such as these is expressed in the form of a hard error (as the code is invalid without a cast). If you plan to make your code usable for other compilers than GCC, the cast is required for the code to work at all, not merely suppressing "harmless" messages.

Comment: @hvd hmmm is there any way other than compiling the project in many different compilers to determine which these warnings are which might be expressed as errors for C99? Or the only way is to just compile it with any compiler. Some times I really take things for granted just cause I am using gcc and it has some hacks, only to learn that they are gcc-only. Such as the buff[20] in scope, long long e.t.c.

Comment: @Lefteris You can use `-std=c99 -pedantic-errors` to compile as C99, disable GCC extensions, and give errors for some (still not all) non-standard-comliant code. By the way, `long long` is defined in C99.

Comment: @interjay It is defined? Oh nice, cause I am using it and thought I would have to find a substitute. I assumed it was not because of the existence of specific gcc warning attributed to long long.

I will be compiling with -std=c99 from now on then. Seems I need to study a bit about the flags of the compiler I am using

Comment: @Lefteris In addition to what interjay said, if you get a warning rather than an error with `-std=c99 -pedantic-errors`, then the code *is* allowed by the standard. What `-pedantic-errors` does is enable all standard-required diagnostics, and upgrades them to hard errors. (However, the behaviour may still be undefined if the code is reached and the condition the warning warns about applies. In addition, some things the standard doesn't allow but doesn't require a diagnostic for will be silently accepted regardless of options.)