# How to disable Assigning to..from incompatible type warning?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gcc

I have a warning in Xcode **Assigning to ... from incompatible type**. It appears when i set delegate of tableView to UIViewController without UITableViewDelegate protocol.

This warnings are annoying and i want to disable it. However i can't find how to do this. Only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448590/inhibiting-the-incompatible-pointer-type-specific-warning-under-gcc) post showed something similar.

- How to disable this warning?
- What is the way to find out how to disable different types of warnings? In case there would be another warning, that i want to disable.

Comment: What's stopping you from making the view controller conform to `UITableViewDelegate`? Sounds like we are facing an XY problem.

Comment: Does your `ViewController` confirms with `UITableViewDelegate` protocol in .h file?

Comment: A delegate that doesn't perform to the right protocol seems more than pointless.

Comment: I have an UIViewController superclass with method to implement initialization of tableView in it for children controllers. This method can be called or might not be called. In reason of not to taking warnings about not implementing tableViewDelegate methods.

Comment: What is wrong with the solution in the question you link to, being to insert a cast `(id<UITableViewDelegate>)`?

Comment: Because than i would get warnings `Method ... in protocol ... not implemented`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are some downvotes from a couple crybabies, but the answer for this question can be useful in some cases. Maybe not in this one but at similar situations.

I finally found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38486958/5790492) and it seems, that the only way now (end 2016) to implement protocol and than use

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wprotocol"
```

Answer (score 0):

This warning appears when your `ViewController` does not confirm with `UITableViewDelegate` protocol in .h file.

To resolve this:

In `ViewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>

@property NSString *myString;

@end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know this. Thats not the answer for the question.